# How TAU function of SM4ni cipher is implemented?

Tags: block-cipher, s-boxes

I am trying to understand the [SIMD implementation of TAU function of SM4](https://github.com/mjosaarinen/sm4ni/blob/master/sm4ni.c) which is as follows:

```
#define SM4_TAU_L1 { \
    y = _mm_and_si128(x, c0f);              \
    y = _mm_shuffle_epi8(m1l, y);           \
    x = _mm_srli_epi64(x, 4);               \
    x = _mm_and_si128(x, c0f);              \
    x = _mm_shuffle_epi8(m1h, x) ^ y;       \
    x = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x, shr);           \
    x = _mm_aesenclast_si128(x, c0f);       \
    y = _mm_andnot_si128(x, c0f);           \
    y = _mm_shuffle_epi8(m2l, y);           \
    x = _mm_srli_epi64(x, 4);               \
    x = _mm_and_si128(x, c0f);              \
    x = _mm_shuffle_epi8(m2h, x) ^ y;       \
    y = x ^ _mm_shuffle_epi8(x, r08) ^      \
        _mm_shuffle_epi8(x, r16);           \
    y = _mm_slli_epi32(y, 2) ^              \
        _mm_srli_epi32(y, 30);              \
    x = x ^ y ^ _mm_shuffle_epi8(x, r24);   \
}
```

it looks as if the SM4 S-box is an affine equivalent of the [Rijndael S-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box) using this formula:

$$SM4= B(raj(A(x\oplus a))\oplus b$$ where (using a search tool):

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 0& 0& 1\\
 1& 1& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0& 1\\
 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 0& 1& 1\\
 1& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 1& 1\\
 1& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1& 0& 1\\
 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 1& 0& 0\\
 1& 1& 1& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0\\
 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix} 
0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 1\\
 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 0& 1& 1\\
 1& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 1\\
 1& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 0& 0\\
 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 0\\
 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 1& 1\\
 0& 0& 1& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0\\
 0& 1& 0& 1& 1& 0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$a=0x75 \space\space , \space\space b=0xfb$$

I applied the decomposition concept used in [SCREAM
Side-Channel Resistant Authenticated Encryption with Masking](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/round2/screamv3.pdf) to obtain four 4-bit lookup tables of each matrix ( it worked); however, my values are different for m1l, m1h, m2l, m2h.

```
  // Affine transform 1 (low and high hibbles)
    const __m128i m1l __attribute__((aligned(0x10))) =
        { 0x9197E2E474720701, 0xC7C1B4B222245157 };
    const __m128i m1h __attribute__((aligned(0x10))) =
        { 0xE240AB09EB49A200, 0xF052B91BF95BB012 };

    // Affine transform 2 (low and high hibbles)
    const __m128i m2l __attribute__((aligned(0x10))) =
        { 0x5B67F2CEA19D0834, 0xEDD14478172BBE82 };
    const __m128i m2h __attribute__((aligned(0x10))) =
        { 0xAE7201DD73AFDC00, 0x11CDBE62CC1063BF };
```

In my understanding, the author used a 4-to-8 bit lookup table, and now my question:

**How did the author derive the values of m1l, m1h, m2l, and m2h?**